# Tubes splitting along seam

Tags: innertube

I'm on my third tube in 2 weeks since I got a flat tyre from a nail.

They're not being punctured, they are all splitting along a seam which isn't even facing the road. I have tried checking for something causing it in the rim or tyre but failed to locate anything. I tried finding different tubes, but all the shops seem to have the same brand of Chinese tubes.

What could be causing this? Can it be prevented?

Comment: How old are the tubes?  I have used one "fresh" from a box, which split just from being handled.  The box was probably a decade old and while tube was pliable, it was also expired perhaps from storage conditions.

Comment: @Criggie I don't know how old they are, I can't read Chinese and didn't keep the boxes. But since they were shipped all the way to mid Pacific thats a potential cause I guess. I didn't know tubes have a finite shelf life. My 20km commute tomorrow wont be much fun

Comment: What condition is your rim tape in?

Comment: @PaulH it looks/feels fine, the wheel itself is about 6 months old and had no issues until the nail puncture

Comment: Maybe not even old, just simply defective, tubes.